# Waking up a thread without risking to get blocked

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have a worker thread running indefinitely, which goes to sleep for one minute if there's nothing to do. Sometimes, another piece of code produces some work and wants to wake the worker thread immediately.

So I did something like this (code for illustration only):

```
class Worker {
    public void run() {
        while (!shuttingDown()) {
           step();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void step() {
        if (hasWork()) {
            doIt();
        } else {
            wait(60_000);
        }
    }

    public synchronized wakeMeUpInside() {
        notify();
    }
}
```

What I dislike is having to enter the monitor only for waking something up, which means that the notifying thread may be delayed for no good reason. As the choices of native synchronization are limited, I thought I'd switch to `Condition`, but it has [exactly the same problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--):

> An implementation may (and typically does) require that the current thread hold the lock associated with this Condition when this method is called.

Comment: I guess, I'm doing something plain stupid... actually, only `wait` and `notify` need to be enclosed in the synchronized block. There's another unrelated synchronization there, which I conflated....

Comment: I'd recommend a `BlockingQueue` instead. That way you can forget `synchronized` and `wait/notify`. You just need to interrupt the thread that's waiting on `queue.poll()` when you shut down.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm aware about `BlockingQueue`, but I'm not sending work to the thread, I'm just notifying it. Also all work (produced by multiple threads) may or may not be executed in a single step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a semaphore based solution:

```
class Worker {
    // If 0 there's no work available
    private workAvailableSem = new Semaphore(0);

    public void run() {
        while (!shuttingDown()) {
           step();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void step() {
        // Try to obtain a permit waiting up to 60 seconds to get one
        boolean hasWork = workAvailableSem.tryAquire(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if (hasWork) {
            doIt();
        }
    }

    public wakeMeUpInside() {
        workAvailableSem.release(1);
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this meets your needs. A few things to note:

- This will add one permit each time `wakeMeUpInside` is called. Thus if two threads wake up the `Worker` it will run `doIt` twice without blocking. You can extend the example to avoid that.
- This waits 60 seconds for work to do. If none is available it'll end up back in the `run` method which will send it immediately back to the `step` method which will just wait again. I did this because I'm assuming you had some reason why you wanted to run every 60 seconds even if there's no work. If that's not the case just call `aquire` and you'll wait indefinitely for work.

As per comments below the OP wants to run only once. While you could call `drainPermits` in that case a cleaner solution is just to use a `LockSupport` like so:

```
class Worker {
    // We need a reference to the thread to wake it
    private Thread workerThread = null;
    // Is there work available
    AtomicBoolean workAvailable = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void run() {
        workerThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (!shuttingDown()) {
           step();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void step() {
        // Wait until work is available or 60 seconds have passed
        ThreadSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(1));
        if (workAvailable.getAndSet(false)) {
            doIt();
        }
    }

    public wakeMeUpInside() {
        // NOTE: potential race here depending on desired semantics.
        // For example, if doIt() will do all work we don't want to
        // set workAvailable to true if the doIt loop is running.
        // There are ways to work around this but the desired
        // semantics need to be specified. 
        workAvailable.set(true);
        ThreadSupport.unpark(workerThread);
    }
}
```

Comment: A good idea, but "it will run `doIt` twice without blocking" really bothers me. I guess, I could just eat up all permits in a loop.

Comment: If you want it to run only once just call `drainPermits`

Comment: But please don't remove the `Semophore`.

Comment: @maaartinus Sure. Kept the Semaphore solution but added one that just directly uses LockSupport to block/unblock the thread.

Comment: Perfect! I'm sure, both solutions will work and I've learnt something. Btw., calling `doIt` needlessly on a race is harmless. Actually, I call it every minute even without a notification as there may be some previously failed work to be retried after a delay. But this is a minor detail...